# How to adjust arrow besides a TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

In this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF) a nice example of a `TreeView` is shown.

Now I would like to have two elements stacked with a `StackPanel` within a `TreeViewItem` vertically:

```
var treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem();
var stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
stackPanel.Children.Add(... some text ...);
stackPanel.Children.Add(... some icon ...);
treeViewItem.Header = stackPanel;
```

The little arrow besides the `TreeViewItem` (to display its subitems) is now placed in the middle - between the icon and the text.

**Question:** Is it possible to adjust the arrow to the top (besides the icon)?

Comment: Seems to me that tutorial is completely wrong. It incurs in all sorts of bad practices. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) is a tutorial that explains the WPF TreeView in a WPF way, rather than carrying over the horrible archaic winforms approaches. WPF general rule: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF, That's what XAML is for. Create a proper ViewModel for this and use DataTemplates or something.

Comment: @HighCore There are no wrong tutorials. This one is actually not bad and it shows you how to use TreeView in Xaml and in Code. It shows you that TreeView may contain controls or pure data as items. John you do not need to add a StackPanel to TreeView's Header just to display the it with two labels. Try using HeaderTemplate instead. Back to your actual question John, it is possible to adjust/change the arrow however you want but it will require you to change the ControlTemplate of TreeViewItem. You can find default TreeViewItem template on MSDN. Copy past it and change it the way you want. :)